# How can I integrate QapTcha ( jQuery captcha plugin) in my asp.net and vb.net registration form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, slider, captcha

I am developing and maintaining an web application built with asp.net and vb.net

On the user registration ; this application is currently using email verification. But My client want to include a slider captcha in the registraion as well. specifically QapTcha ( jQuery captcha plugin)

Please see below my code for registration page

**Registration.aspx**

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/c/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="registration.aspx.vb" Inherits="c_registration" %>

 <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/c/MasterPage.master" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="myVal" Namespace="Mypeoplebiz.MyValidators" Assembly="App_Code" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server"></asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="Server">
     <h2>Registration  </h2>

     <div class="jsreg-wrapper">

         <asp:Literal ID="litMessage" runat="server" />
         <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
         <asp:Panel ID="panForm" runat="server" Visible="false">

                 <label>Title <span class="small">(required)</span></label>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="uxTitleID" runat="server" CssClass="" ataTextField="name"  DataValueField="id" EnableViewState="False" />

                 <label>First Name <span class="small">(required)</span></label>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="uxName" runat="server" CssClass="" MaxLength="30" EnableViewState="False" />

                 <label>Surname <span class="small">(required)</span></label>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="uxSurname" runat="server" CssClass="" MaxLength="30"
                EnableViewState="False" />

                 <h3>Login details to track applications</h3>
                <label>Email Address <span class="small">(required)</span></label>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="uxEmail" runat="server" CssClass="" MaxLength="100"
                EnableViewState="False" />

                <label>Password <span class="small">(required)</span></label>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="uxPassword" runat="server" CssClass="" MaxLength="20"
                EnableViewState="False" TextMode="Password" />

                <label>Confirm Password <span class="small">(required)</span></label>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="uxPasswordConfirm" runat="server" CssClass="" TextMode="Password" />

                <p class="alert">To complete your registration please click submit.</p>

         </asp:Panel>

     </div>

     <div class="jsreg-error">

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must complete the 'Surname'." ControlToValidate="uxSurname" EnableViewState="False" ValidationGroup="candidateregistration" Display="None" />

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must complete the 'Email Address'."   ControlToValidate="uxEmail" EnableViewState="False" ValidationGroup="candidateregistration" Display="None" />

            <asp:CustomValidator ID="uxEmailValUnique" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This email address is already in use"  ControlToValidate="uxEmail" EnableViewState="False" ValidationGroup="candidateregistration" Display="None" />

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="uxPasswordValReq" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must enter a 'Password'."  ControlToValidate="uxPassword" EnableViewState="False" alidationGroup="candidateregistration" Display="None" />

            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" ControlToCompare="uxPassword" ControlToValidate="uxPasswordConfirm"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="The 'Password' and 'Password Confirmation' do not match." ValidationGroup="candidateregistration" Display="None" />

            <asp:CustomValidator ID="uxPassword6Chars" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Your password must be greater than 5 characters" EnableViewState="false" ValidationGroup="candidateregistration" Display="None" />

     </div>
     <div class="btn-wrapper">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uxSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="SaveClick" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="candidateregistration" CssClass="btn" />


     </div>
   </div>
 </asp:Content>
```

**Registration.aspx.vb**

```
    Partial Class c_registration

        Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

            With Candidate

                uxName.Text = .Name
                uxSurname.Text = .Surname
                uxEmail.Text = .Email
                uxPassword.Text = .Password
                uxPasswordConfirm.Text = .Password

                If Request("email") IsNot Nothing Then
                    uxEmail.Text = Request("email").ToString.Trim.ToLower
                End If

            End With


        End Sub


        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

                    If Not (panForm.Visible) Then
                        uxSubmit.Visible = False
                    End If

        End Sub


        Public Sub SaveClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

                    If Not Page.IsValid Then
                                litMessage.Text = ""
                                Exit Sub
                    End If


                     With Candidate

                                .TitleID = uxTitleID.SelectedValue
                                .Name = Left(uxName.Text.Trim, 100)
                                .Surname = Left(uxSurname.Text.Trim, 100)
                                .Email = uxEmail.Text.Trim
                                .Password = uxPassword.Text.Trim

                    End With

                    Dim Email As Core.Email

                    Email = New Core.Email

                    With Email
                                .ContentID = 6
                                .Replacement("logo", IIf(_employerlogo <> "", _employerlogo, ""))
                                .Replacement("SiteName", _employer.Name & " Career Portal")
                                .Replacement("CandidateEmail", Candidate.Email)
                                .Replacement("CandidateFirstName", Candidate.Name)
                                .Replacement("CandidatePassword", Candidate.Password)
                                .Send()
                    End With

                    Mypeoplebiz.User.Authenticate(Candidate.Email, Candidate.Password)

                    Dim rurl = "registration-complete.aspx?e=" & Request("e") & "&b=" & CInt(Request("b")) & (IIf(IsNothing(Request("i")), "", "&i=" & Request("i"))) & "&hp=" & Request("hp") & "&hI=" & Request("hI")

                    Response.Redirect(rurl)

        End Sub
End Class
```

I want to include  QapTcha ( jQuery captcha plugin) before the submit button

In the following link there is demonstration about how to use the plugin in a php based web application.

http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/qaptcha

But  how can I include this QapTcha ( jQuery captcha plugin) in my asp.net and VB.net web application.

I know there are other ususal captcha available .  but my client is specially interested in slider type captcha

Please help me with code. if you need further information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full asp.net guide can be found here:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-implement-Captcha-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: Do you know any asp.net guide to include slider captcha?

Comment: The link I included is the guide. Between the article and the documentation it should be trivial to implement. Please don't look for a full implemented solution in SO.